# How to read/write xml files using Drupal 6

Tags: php, xml, drupal

I would like to know how can I parse XML files and perform read write operations using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API for this in Drupal -- use the [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) extension from PHP. It works wonders.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Drupal or PHP....so can you tell if I should make a php script for doing this process inside drupal

Comment: Sorry but no. This is a separate question and you need to elaborate a lot more to be able to answer. Like, what should trigger an XML parsing event ... ? What do you write out ... ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specifics of what you need to do. Modules such as [Import / Export API](http://drupal.org/project/importexportapi), [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource), [XML Parser](http://drupal.org/project/xml_parser), and [others](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=drupal_core:87&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc&text=simplexml) may be useful, depending on what exactly you need to accomplish.

Also, this [XML Parser](https://github.com/pvhee/feeds_xmlparser) for the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is a PHP application. There is no specific XML API in Drupal and any PHP one can be used in a custom module for a specific user case or feature. There is [a large collection of XML APIs in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php). If you have experience with jQuery, look also at [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and the [QueryPath module](http://drupal.org/project/querypath) for Drupal.

You will need to [create a module](http://drupal.org/node/231276) to embed your custom PHP code in your Drupal site.

As pointed by Matt V., there is a [lot of modules in Drupal that deal with XML](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/xml). Some may fit your needs and avoid you to write any custom code.